# In Scala, why is there no implementation for `Future.onComplete`?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, future

In the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L1) of `Future` module, I saw the definition of `onComplete` like this:

```
  /** When this future is completed, either through an exception, or a value,
   *  apply the provided function.
   *
   *  If the future has already been completed,
   *  this will either be applied immediately or be scheduled asynchronously.
   *
   *  $multipleCallbacks
   *  $callbackInContext
   */
  def onComplete[U](@deprecatedName('func) f: Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

This looks strange because it has no function body (no implementation). So why could the `onComplete` work? Is it implemented in Java? How can I find the real implementation codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dig a little deeper. How do you normally create a `Future`? One way is `Future.apply`.

[What does it do?](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L492)

```
 def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit @deprecatedName('execctx) executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = impl.Future(body)
```

[`impl.Future.apply`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Future.scala#L29-L33) creates a `PromiseCompletingRunnable` which holds a `Promise`.

```
  def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): scala.concurrent.Future[T] = {
    val runnable = new PromiseCompletingRunnable(body)
    executor.prepare.execute(runnable)
    runnable.promise.future
  }
```

In particular, it creates a `Promise.DefaultPromise`, [which implements `onComplete`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L267-L271). In the same source file you can also see that the default `Promise` implementation is also a `Future`. When we call `promise.future`, it just returns itself as a `Future`. So it's all there in the standard library.

If you were to [search the Scala repository for "def onComplete"](https://github.com/scala/scala/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22def%20onComplete%22), you only get a few results, so it was pretty easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

`Future` is a `trait` which means that it does not have to have an implementation; it can be left abstract to be implemented by something else.  In this case, you are probably going to end up with some form of [`Promise`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala):

```
def onComplete[U](func: Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit = {
      val preparedEC = executor.prepare()
      val runnable = new CallbackRunnable[T](preparedEC, func)
      dispatchOrAddCallback(runnable)
    }
```